# dump specific excel cell data

Tags: php, excel

I am unable to get the code to work...  I am attempting to pull data from an excel file into php.  I have used the reader successfully in dumping the data from an entire sheet, but I want to echo only a specific cell.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
require_once 'PHPexcel.php';
function toNumber($dest)
{
    if ($dest)
        return ord(strtolower($dest)) - 96;
    else
        return 0;
}

function myFunction($s,$x,$y){
 $x = toNumber($x);
 return $s->getCellByColumnAndRow($x, $y)->getFormattedValue();
}


$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($excel);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($menu.xls);
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheetData = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();


$cellData = myFunction($sheetData,'B','2');
var_dump($cellData);
?>
```

I get an error that the page is not working.

Comment: I have also tried requiring the 'excel_reader2.php' library.

Comment: So what Reader library are you actually using? Some of your calls suggest PHPExcel, although you're including something totally different

Comment: To read data from a specific cell using PHPExcel, you'd use something like `$cellDataForCellA1 = $sheetData->getCell('A1')->getValue()`.... as described in the documentation and the examples

Comment: Do you see any errors within the functions?  I replaced my $cellData variable with yours and i still got the same error.

Comment: Well `toNumber()` is completely redundant (PHPExcel provides functions to do that for you); and if you pass in a column letter to your functions, then why convert to a number to use `getCellByColumnAndRow()` when you can simply use `getCell()` using the `A1` style address?